# error reading information on service docker.service: No such file or directory

Tags: docker

I am trying to add docker.service start on linux boot

```
sudo chkconfig --add docker.service
```

it gives me this error

```
error reading information on service docker.service: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

Comment: Yep guess the old way chkconfig looks for an /etc/init.d/xxx file which it didn't have, just the new way (docker.service file)